# Is it possible to save exact result of select query in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql

I need to persist result of select statement in t-sql.
It can be anything: stored procedure or view but anytime i invoke it it should return exactly same data even when original tables where modified. is it possible?

UPDATE:
the basic idea is to let user to mark result set with name and allow to filter by it in future.
for example:

1. user filters 'accounts' table by some condition. saves the result set and send email to all filtered accounts.
2. next days some new accounts were created that meet condition. but email should be sent only to new ones.

but solution should be general enough to allow mark result sets from different tables

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: How can it return identical result if data of the table has changed???

Comment: May be you could create a table and store your results in it forever.

Comment: Is the idea so bad? If you have temporary tables or volatile data and you need version control, how can you persist the state with database only? @Kaf: But if the schema is different or changes, you'd need a lot of tables just to persist unavailable or changed tables/views/queries.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I am not very sure what the requirement is. May be user could save query results into a static table and query it to get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have to store those results in some special table.